# Configure Celery with JSON Serializer (Python + node.js)

Tags: python, json, node.js, celery, node-celery

I'm running a Celery worker in Python with the [`celery` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery) **v3.1.25**, and a Celery client in node.js with the [`node-celery` npm package](https://github.com/mher/node-celery) v0.2.7 *(not the latest)*.

The Python Celery worker works fine when sending a job using a Python Celery client.

**Problem:** When using a `node-celery` client to send a task to the Celery backend, we get an error in the JS console:

> (STDERR) Celery should be configured with json serializer

Python Celery worker is configured with:

```
app = Celery('tasks', 
    broker='amqp://test:test@192.168.1.26:5672//',
    backend='amqp://',
    task_serializer='json',
    include=['proj.tasks'])
```

`node-celery` client is configured with:

```
var celery = require('node-celery')
var client = celery.createClient({
    CELERY_BROKER_URL: 'amqp://test:test@192.168.1.26:5672//',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: 'amqp',
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER: "json"
});

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');

    client.call('proj.tasks.getPriceEstimates', [start_latitude, start_longitude],
        function(result) {
            console.log('result: ', result);
            client.end();
        })
});
```

Is this a problem with the configuration on the Python Celery worker? Did we miss out on a configuration parameter which can change the return serialization format to `json`?

---

## Update

Updated with `result_serializers` and `accept_content` parameters as suggested by ChillarAnand

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', 
    broker='amqp://test:test@192.168.1.26:5672//',
    backend='amqp://',
    task_serializer='json',
    result_serializer='json',
    accept_content=['application/json'],
    include=['proj.tasks'])
```

But node.js Celery client still thinks that its not in `json`, throwing the same error message.

It gives that error because the [results were in the form of `'application/x-python-serialize'`](https://github.com/mher/node-celery/blob/master/celery.js?MobileOptOut=1#L337-L338).

Checked this to be the case, as RabbitMQ management console shows the results to be `content_type:  application/x-python-serialize`

---

[This forum post says that](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.amqp.celery.user/5168) it is because the tasks were created before the configs were loaded.

Here are how my files are like:

**proj/celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', 
    broker='amqp://test:test@192.168.1.26:5672//',
    backend='amqp://',
    task_serializer='json',
    result_serializer='json',
    accept_content=['application/json'],
    include=['proj.tasks'])
```

**proj/tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app

@app.task
def myTask():
    ...
    return ...
```

Is there a better way to structure the code to ensure that the configs are loaded before the tasks?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

When configuring a serializer, you should specify content type, task serializer and result serializer as well.

```
app = Celery(
    broker='amqp://guest@localhost//',
    backend='amqp://',
    include=['proj.tasks'],

    task_serializer='json',
    result_serializer='json',
    accept_content = ['application/json'],
)
```

Comment: I made the suggested changes for my Python Celery worker. but the node client is still giving the same error when receiving the results. I believe it gives that error because the [results was in the form of `'application/x-python-serialize'`](https://github.com/mher/node-celery/blob/master/celery.js?MobileOptOut=1#L337-L338). Any other setting to make to switch it to `json`?

Comment: For celery_node app, did you set `CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json', CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json'`?